# Switching/Creating New Apple ID

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id

I have an iPhone with 64 GB of storage and for a long time it has not been enough! I recently learned about using iCloud storage to free up storage on my iPhone (is this true?). So, I wanted to some iCloud storage so I can put all my photos and videos there and free up phone storage. My real issue is that for years, I have been using my dad's Apple ID (also, we don't use iCloud). But I want my own apple account to maybe my own iCloud account and put videos and photos there. My question is, will I lose anything when signing out of my dads account on my phone and signing in to mine? If so, how do I avoid this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is true. iCloud is a very helpful service provided by Apple in this sense. As long as you are not signed into an iCloud account for photos, and you do not fully factory reset the phone, the photos will remain.

Here are the steps to transfer your Apple ID (adapted from from [readdle.com](https://readdle.com/manage-apple-id-account-tutorial)):

> Part I: Sign Out of Apple ID on iPhone or iPad
>
> Launch the Settings app on your iPhone or iPad
> Tap the Apple ID Name & Photo at the top of the screen.
> Scroll down a bit and then tap the Sign Out link.
> If you use the same account for iCloud and the iTunes Store, you’ll be asked to enter your Apple ID password. If you use two different accounts, you’ll be given three options:
>
> - Sign Out of iCloud and iTunes Store
> - Sign Out of iCloud
> - Sign Out of iTunes Store
>
> Select which data from iCloud you want to keep on the device and which data you want to delete using the toggle switches. Tap Sign Out again to remove the Apple ID from your iPhone or iPad.

> Part II: Sign In with a Different Apple ID on your iPhone or iPad.
>
> Now that you have managed to remove the Apple ID that was previously being used on an iPhone or iPad let us now see how you can Sign In with a different Apple ID on the iOS device.
>
> Launch the Settings app on your iPhone or iPad. Tap the Sign in to your iPhone/Sign in to your iPad link at the top of the screen. If you see a Name or Photo here, follow the steps outlined in Part I above. Enter the email address or phone number associated with the different Apple ID you want to sign in with. Then enter your Apple ID password. If you already have some data on your device, such as Contacts, Calendars, Bookmarks, etc., you will be asked if you want to Merge that data with this new Apple ID you are Signing In with. Tap Merge if you want to merge data. Otherwise, tap Don’t Merge.

Comment: I really appreciate the response! Thank you for going in such depth! I will deifniltey make sure to follow all these steps. Just to clarify- in addition to all my photos remaining, will my original contacts, text messages, apps, etc. also remain saved?

Comment: @SneSar most data stays on-device when you sign out, and will be uploaded to the new account when you sign back in. However, I'm not sure about Contacts if they're stored in iCloud. However, since it sounds like you'll retain access to the old account, its safe to try.

Comment: @SneSar For apps, they will remain downloaded but will be associated with the old account and require its password to update. You can use "Family Sharing" to pair the accounts and preserve access, if you've spent substantial money on apps.

Comment: @Ezekiel Thank you for clarifying about contacts an apps! Hopefully everythign stays. Just to clarify, I don't have an iCloud account of my own, and nor does my dad have an iCloud for his apple account. So nothing is currently saved to any iCloud account.

Comment: Ah, if there's no existing iCloud account then just signing in will be perfectly safe. For App Store purchases, yes those will still be tied to whatever account was used.